# In Hibernate how to ignore associated table in selection

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am using spring boot and Hibernate and I have two tables **order** and **orderdetails** and I need two queries, first I want to select records in order along with records that relate to that order in order detail table which works fine, but when I want to select only records from order table I can't because it will bring all associated records for each order in the order detail(just like the first one). How I can select records from the order without selecting related records in order detail table?

I also tried to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation but it doesn't work like what I want.

My entity classes

***orders***

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Orders {

@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private Long orderId;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private LocalDate createdDate;

private String status;

private float amount;

@Transient
String error;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private List<OrderDetail> orderDetails;
}
```

***order detail***

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class OrderDetail {

public OrderDetail() {
}

public OrderDetail(Long productId, String productName, int quantity, float unitPrice, float subtotalPrice){
    this.productId = productId;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.subtotalPrice = subtotalPrice;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "order_detail_id", nullable = false)
Long orderDetailId;

@Column(name = "product_id")
Long productId;

@Column(name = "product_name")
String productName;

int quantity;

@Column(name = "unit_price")
float unitPrice;

@Column(name = "subtotal_price")
float subtotalPrice;
}
```

Queries that I tried:

```
    @Query(value = "select orders.order_id, orders.amount, orders.created_date, orders.status, orders.user_id, " +
        "orders.user_name from orders where orders.user_id = :userid", nativeQuery = true)
List<Orders> selectAllOrdersOfSpecificUser(@Param("userid") Long userId);

==================================================================================
    List<Orders> findAllByUserId(Long userId);
```

Both of them bring all the records from the orders table and associated records in the order detail table.

Answer (score 0):

FetchType.EAGER will retrive all the orderdetails as well. Use FetchType.LAZY and create a special JOIN FETCH query for getting orderdetails with orders.

Comment: I tried to use FetchType.Lazy before but it showed me "could not initialize proxy - no Session" error so I added "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true" to "application.properties" but still get the same result.